# Create a view of nodes by taxonomy id

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

On my website, the user first fills out a questionnaire. Based on the answers given, I want to generate a view. The answers correspond to taxonomy ids. The problem is that I can't seem to find any option to filter by taxonomy id, which I am passing to my view as an argument.

Is there any way to do this? Preferably through the GUI, but code is no problem.

There was an option in drupal 6 that could do this on a regular page ([taxonomy_render_nodes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_render_nodes/6)), but this has disappeared in drupal 7, which is why I'm looking to create a view now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter by taxonomy term in your view you can do this by adding a contextual filter (arguments in D6).

If you can pass the term id then you can do the following:

When adding a contextual filter choose "Content:Has taxonomy term ID".
Under "MORE" there is an option "Allow multiple values".

You can play around with these options as I never get it right on the first go.

Comment: Your answer made me realise what I did wrong. I was trying to use the term names on the term id filter... Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Taxonomy_select_nodes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7). Not sure how the implementation would be via views but this appears to what your looking for.

Comment: That only returns the id of the term. I use this already to generate my list of terms that I'm going to pass to the view. The problem is implementing this in a filter